# Progress bar give NullPointerException

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have two class. class A is **activity** where my progress bar will be use. and class B is **no-activity** where my progress bar will be update. but when i calling progress bar from non-activity class B . i got null  pointer exception.

class A:-

```
ProgressBar progressBar; 
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);}
```

class B:-

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

             int i = 0;
             int progressStatus = 0;

             public void run() {
                 while (progressStatus < 100) {
                     progressStatus += doWork();
                     try {
                         Thread.sleep(500);
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

                     // Update the progress bar
                     ((Activity) cnt).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                         public void run() {
                            XMPPClient xc = new XMPPClient();
                            xc.progressBar = new ProgressBar(cnt);
                            xc.progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        //  Toast.makeText(cnt, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             i++;
                         }
                     });
                 }
             }
             private int doWork() {

                 return i * 3;
              }
        }).start();

when i added this line :-  xc.progressBar = new ProgressBar(cnt);
then i did not get nullpointerexception. But now my progress bar is **not updating.**
```

please any one help me.

Comment: you have to give reference of progress bar in class b. and then use it and dismiss it

Comment: but how may i do it plz?

Comment: send progressbar as paramter in classB constructor From ActivityA and use it in classb

Comment: plz make answer. i want accept your due to first abhishesh :)

Comment: :) i have declare my answer below please check it :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ProgressBar progressBar; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    ClassB classb = new ClassB(this, progressBar);
}

public class ClassB{

    private Context cnt;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ClassB(Context context, ProgressBar pBar){
         cnt = context;
         progressBar = pBar;
    }
}
```

Now you can use progressBar instead of creating a new one like you did in previous code!
Just a quick overview...

Answer (score 0):

in ClassA :-

```
  ProgressBar progressBar; 
         @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


       ////Then Use the Reference on Progressbar 

       ClassB classb = new ClassB(this, progressBar);
    }
```

Then in ClassB :-

```
public class ClassB{

    private Context cnt;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ClassB(Context context, ProgressBar pBar){
         cnt = context;
         progressBar = pBar;

 new Thread(new Runnable() {

             int i = 0;
             int progressStatus = 0;

             public void run() {
                 while (progressStatus < 100) {
                     progressStatus += doWork();
                     try {
                         Thread.sleep(500);
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

                     // Update the progress bar
                     ((Activity) cnt).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                         public void run() {
                            XMPPClient xc = new XMPPClient();
                            xc.progressBar = new ProgressBar(cnt);
                            xc.progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        //  Toast.makeText(cnt, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             i++;
                         }
                     });
                 }
             }
             private int doWork() {

                 return i * 3;
              }
        }).start();


    }
```